# Add tag(s) to accepted answers

Tags: discussion, tags

If an answer to a "How should I do X?" question recommends a particular technology and is accepted, should the tag for that technology be added to the question?

The reason for doing so is that it makes it easier to search for uses of that technology.

On the other hand I can think of a few reasons against, including putting off other answerers, and possibly implying that the question is more specific than originally intended.

I'm sure there are more reasons both for and against. I'm interested in seeing other's opinions.

Answer (score 9):

I'd say no, since there would be many answers with other technologies, and they all can't be referenced.  The text search will hopefully pick it up.

Answer (score 3):

No, the question tags are for what is asked in the question, not for the answers.

Suppose the OP changes his mind and selects another answer. Should we then have to retag the question to reflect this? Think not.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possibly a valid idea, but I'm sure there will be drawbacks (possible tag spam, etc.).  I can't say how many times I've answered some type of question using some random combination of technologies which generally has the same solution but because the OP's ignorance of some subject, he/she has no idea what the real problem is.

I'm not sure that the tag soup should be the same as the questioners available tags, though.

For instance, a user might have some problem relating about some random set of javascript or server-side libraries and cannot find a solution, but the *real* problem is that he/she's injecting all kinds of fancy non/html encoded text into his html, which generally would be as long as his text cannot be interpreted as html, but it is interpret-able as html, which either changes the markup causing side effects or causes his/her browser to barf.  Thus, the answer would be to html encode his text to avoid a unintentional *injection-attack*.  So, generically, someone identifying the solution might tag her answer as *avoid-injection-attack*.

Edit:  Actually, I just realized the OPs request is different from mine.  The OP wants to tag accepted answers.  I do feel that's a bad approach (accepted answers aren't always the right answer).  I wanted the ability to add tags to *any* answer.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This could actually be indicative of a problem with the question. The best questions are about a real, actual problem, so if the answer to the question is "use this cool technology `insert link`" then the problem might be that the question isn't a good fit for the site. If the question is about how to use a certain technology, then the only tags on the question should be what the asker is asking about. In short, sometimes askers don't understand what their problem is, so it could be valid to add that in after the fact.

Comment: I would also agree that this might indicate a problem with the question, but even well thought out questions may have similarly simple solutions (in my example, maybe the OP thinks things are htmlencoded by default or whatever). That's also why I don't think tags for answers ought to be the same set as those for questions (unless *perhaps* the OP misidentified where the problem lays).  Furthermore, it might be useful to search answers which are tagged similarly; injection attacks don't only happen in html.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be a fan of the site if you could tell if the question has an accepted answer or not just from the main screen / search results.

Sure, the questions that have an accepted answer are quite likely to have a decent useful answer, but that doesn't mean questions that *haven't* had an answer accepted are going to have *bad* answers.

I am concerned that if you could tell from a search whether or not questions had accepted answers that people would start to avoid reading unaccepted questions because they think that *'if it's not got an accepted answer then there is no point me reading this one'*, and that is invariably unlikely to be true.

You can already see if there are any answers associated to a question, and to me that is enough to tell if you're going to get useful information from the question. If an answer is truly *bad* then (At least I'd like to think) it'd be flagged and deleted, so any existing answer that remains would be of at least *some* use to the situation.

Comment: You *can* tell if an answer has been accepted from the main page and search results: for questions with an accepted answer, the answer count is coloured yellow instead of white.

Comment: Sometimes a question has an accepted answer but you can give an even better one. One of my answers is out-scoring a high-rated accepted answer by a ratio of about 2 to 1, and it's just an alternate method for doing it (that happens to not require special tools or real programming).