# Tag proposal: Tag for logical/language-understanding errors

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Do we have a tag for questions about logical errors where the code turns out to be syntactically correct but the programmer misunderstood some part of the language?

Example question:

[Convert Unicode data to int in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476484/convert-unicode-data-to-int-in-python)

This would mostly be used for tagging questions after they have been answered. Then later when someone think they may have a problem like this they could search for the new tag plus the tag for the language they're using, to hopefully find their answer, before they create a duplicate.

I started writing this question thinking it would be a good idea, but I'm not so sure anymore, but I'm not sure enough that it's a bad idea to not ask.

If we want it, what should the tag be?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't sound like a good idea. That would be a meta-tag, and we [don't want those](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

That tag could be added to an incredible number of questions, so it wouldn't be of much help as a search filter.

In general, tags shouldn't be added based on the answers the question received, or the solutions provided. They should classify the question itself. If the OP knows that their problem is likely due to a misunderstanding of the language they're using, they can simply state that in their question. Adding a generic [language-confusion](/questions/tagged/language-confusion) tag wouldn't really help.

Comment: _In general, tags shouldn't be added based on the answers the question received, or the solutions provided._ Is this documented anywhere because I've managed to overlook it then, and had edits to this effect accepted, so I can't be the only one who did.

Comment: [Here is one question that deals with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59333/should-we-retag-questions-with-topics-proposed-in-the-answers?lq=1), but the consensus isn't as strong as I thought. (See the linked questions for other opinions/variations/situations.) That wasn't actually the main point of my answer to your question here. Meta-tags are bad, don't create them.

Comment: Yeah I got the meta-tag part, not sure if I agree or not, but the part about only tagging based on the question was new to me.